# Caching Solutions For A Customized Ticket System

Tags: cache

I have created a ticket system in EE that is customized for reporting and alerts.  It's all front-end but I want to make sure that it's snappy.  Is there a good caching add-on you have used that is worth the money?

Comment: You should change the title of this question to Caching Solutions or something similar.

Comment: good call, makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CE-Cache. Use it. It's static file cache creates flat generated cache files that serve **instantly** on a site that gets 500k hits a week, over a million requests during the semester. You can use the cache breaking feature to break cache when you update channel entries, relationship, basically anything.

I can't speak for the alternative caching methods it provides, but the static cache method is baller (I don't work for them or make any money from them, it just works great).

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache

Comment: I have been looking at that solution, I have never used a caching system before.  I am being careful about the add-ons, even caching, I already have a ton installed.  I will check them out again before I make a decision.  Thank you for letting me know the low down on the add-on.  It's good to hear from someone that already has it working.

Comment: No problem! I'm sure there are other good caching solutions, but this one has worked really well for the university I work at, which touts about 10,000 pages.

Comment: @jchrono-battle What university?  I'm at UMASS Boston.  We do pretty much the same thing as you.